# 2 led on latching pushbutton NO arduino

Tags: led, switches, dpdt

I am looking to push a button and one led comes on when i push the same button again the first led goes off and the second light comes on. alternating lights each time the button is pressed.  one light should always be on.

I was hoping to use a microswitch as the button i want to use has a microswitch that i was going to switch.  Would this be a dpdt?  Does that exist in a latching pushbutton.  Any other  circuit ideas that would work?

I appreciate the input

Answer (score 2):

An alternating (push-on, push-off) pushbutton switch would be the easiest. It needs to be SPDT (or better). There are plenty available.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpxcww.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you want to connect it to an MCU or other logic, then R2 can be used to assure a valid '0' logic level, otherwise you don't need R2.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility if you just want to use a cheap SPST tact switch:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fh02lJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This will work because the [74LVC1G74](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74LVC1G74.pdf) has a Schmitt trigger clock input, which allows a simple RC to be used to debounce the switch. If power is applied with a reasonably fast rise time, the circuit will power up with the Q output low (D1 on) and /Q high (D2 off). That can be reversed by tying the D input to +5 rather than 0V.

Comment: You could put a simply RC delay on the S input of the flop to make sure the flop came up in the preferred state.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have push-on, push-off switches then you can implement the following circuit using mostly digital components.

The input stage is a classic cross-coupled NAND de-bounce circuit that will get rid of any glitches coming from pressing the button. The second stage is just a basic D-type flip flog configure as a T-Type (Toggle) flip-flop.

Finally you can use the flops complimentary outputs to drive your LED circuit. Depending on the flip-flop you use, you may not need the output transistor stage.

Note: All values are approximate. I just used the default circuit wizard values.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fntL8j.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>